# eliminar en un Data Frame una columna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, eliminar

soy principiante y tengo una duda básica: trato de eliminar en una Data Frame dfVentas una columna así: `df.pop("Column 5")`, pero no está funcionando.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, agrega más contexto en la pregunta: lee [ask].

Comment: "No está funcionando" no es algo que pueda ayudar a los demás a saber qué está pasando. En qué sentido no funciona? Obtienes un error? No hay error pero no obtienes lo qu esperabas? Qué esperabas? Qué obtienes?